# Word for "Raccoon-like" or "Raccoon-esque"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I am looking for a word like lupine only for raccoons. Is there a word that means “raccoon-like” or “raccoon-esque”?

Comment: You could coin 'procyonic' if you thought you might be understood...

Comment: @jam I presume you're getting that from the linnaen name term for racoon. But I understand that "procyon" is actually Greek for "before the dog", so I'm not sure if that would be appropriate. In any case, it makes me think of the star, not an animal.

Comment: racooniform, unless you don't want a joke, and of course racuneiform if you want the less jocular form with inexplicable spelling.

Comment: Raccoony - sounds to good to keep quiet about.

Comment: I would say that someone who is "raccoon-like" is a *raccoonteur*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[ODO on raccoon](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/raccoon)

> Genus *Procyon,* family *Procyonidae* (the raccoon family): two species, in particular the common raccoon (*P. lotor*), which often occurs in urban areas in North America. The raccoon family also includes the coati, kinkajou, cacomistle, and olingo

*Procyonide, procyonic, procyonine* perhaps. There must be a rule for forming an adjective from a Greek noun ending *-ον.*

Comment: [Here's something](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animal_names#Terms_by_species_or_taxon) to strengthen your case. [Here](http://www.onelook.com/?w=procyonine) too.

Comment: @coleopterist Wow. It's a General Reference question.

Comment: @coleopterist great links. Hardly General Reference though!

Comment: I vote for procyonic, since it's the one I came up with on my own before the search lead me here.

Answer (score 3):

By analogy to wolves(species), the word would be lotorine. However, that term does not occur on the web; although there *is* a pun about a coon being arrested for 'lotoring'.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for a technical term or something that would be understood in normal conversation? If the former ... I don't know of any, and couldn't find one with an (admittedly brief) search. If the latter, you can find the word "racoonish" used frequently.

Answer (score 1):

Though your request was for a word, since there does not seem to be one that is readily understood, how about one of these phrase-structures **"...of a raccoon"** or **"racoon-like..."** instead?

Examples:

> - It had the nimble dexterity **of a racoon**
> - It lumbered by with a distinct **racoon-like** gait
> - The bandit's mask gave him a comical **racoon-like** appearance